# Possible ways to continuously call server method in SignalR Hub with parameters

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a requirement where server method needs to be called continuously in the same way as clients continuously listen to subscribed events and get notified on any trigger.

Having a button to initiate server event doesn't meet the requirement like in the following example because the client needs to update its location continuously in the database (assuming that it is moving).

```
   $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
          myChatHub.server.broadcastMessageToAll("Peace", 'World');
   });
```

Initially, I thought of using a timer which ticks in every 2-3 minutes, but I am sure there is a better way to do it in SignalR.

Please suggest me the right way to do so.

Comment: I think your timer idea is the way to go. For clients updating their location, a simple Web API POST (or GET) should be sufficient. SignalR is great for realtime communication from Server to client, but unnecessary for the call to server in your example. On the Server, the API endpoint can then broadcast the message to all subscribers.

Comment: Hi, @reckface thanks for the comment. If the API endpoint will be responsible for broadcasting the message to all subscribers then I think API would need to implement SignalR client libraries. Please confirm. 
I have kept SignalR server in separate projet.

Comment: I think we are talking cross purposes. The API endpoint just receives requests. Generally in the same ASP.net project that contains the SignalR server. Once the client (JavaScript clients in your case) initialises the SignalR connection it will receive messges broadcast form the server.